# Protecting against skipping static variable initialization

Tags: c++, static, initialization

I've run in to a nasty error when compiling on gcc4.8, the gist of which is below:

```
#include <iostream>

//time_span.h
struct time_span_t
{
    static time_span_t end;

    time_span_t(int seconds_) : seconds(seconds_) { }

    time_span_t& operator+=(const time_span_t& rhs)
    {
        seconds += rhs.seconds;
        return (*this);
    }

    int seconds;
};

//foo.h
struct foo_t
{
    static time_span_t bar;
};

//order of static initialization unreliable!
//{

//foo.cpp
time_span_t foo_t::bar = time_span_t::end;

//time_span.cpp
time_span_t time_span_t::end = time_span_t(100000);

//}

//main.cpp
int main()
{
    time_span_t test = time_span_t(10);
    test += foo_t::bar;

    std::cout << test.seconds << std::endl; //prints 10
}
```

The issue is that `foo_t::bar` will sometimes be uninitialized.  On most compilers I've tried this on, the variable is properly initialized before being used.

So my question is whether or not there is a standard way to protect against this kind of problem?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will definitely be initialized by the time `main` runs. By the way, `time_span_t time_span_t::end(100000);` and `time_span_t test(10);` are enough.

Comment: I have updated the code to better illustrate the problem.

Comment: Yeah, that's more of a problem. See the static initialization order fiasco.

Comment: Is it really a case of that? There is only one static variable here.

Comment: @CharlesPehlivanian, The updated code has two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All global variables included in the executable will be initialized before `main()` is entered. The only way you can access an uninitialized global variable is to access it while initializing another global variable. With a translation unit it can easily be avoided to access uninitialized global variable by listing those accessed during the initialization of other first. Between translation units hte order of initialization is undefined, however.